# Sitecore (v6.4.1) rich text editor with line numbers

Tags: sitecore

1) Is there a option in Sitecore (6.4.1) rich text editor that will show line numbers? 
2) Does Sitecore rich text editor use Telerik RAD Controls?

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore uses Telerik's RAD Editor as its default rich text editor. As far as I can see there is no way to get line numbers to appear for content in RAD Editor.

It is possible to *format* the content to have line numbers in it using the *FormatCodeBlock* option ([info here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/xhtmlvalidatortrackchangesformatcodeblockdialogs/defaultcs.aspx)), this is not enabled by default and if you want to know how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Hi stephen, could you please tell me how to do this. some good resources would be helpful

Comment: If you switch to the 'core' database and go to : `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Toolbar 1` .. make a duplicate of a button (e.g.'Find') and name it `Format Code Block` .. in the `Click` field set it to `FormatCodeBlock`.

When you switch back to master and open your Rich Text editor you should now see the new button which will open up the 'FormatCodeBlock' dialogue.